# Python script error json2csv file error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a code json2csv file written for me in python(which I named json2csv.py).

```
import sys, json, csv

input = open(sys.argv[1])
json_array = json.load(input)
input.close()

item_data = json_array["items"]

if len(item_data) >= 1:
    first_item_id = item_data[0].keys()[0]
    columns = item_data[0][first_item_id].keys()

csv_file = open(sys.argv[2], "wb")
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
# there is currently a known bug where column names are partially uppercase, this will be fixed soon. the "map(lambda x: x.lower(), columns)" fixes this issue in the mean time
writer.writerow(map(lambda x: x.lower(), columns)) 

# here .items() is a standard python function
for item_id, item_data in item_data[0].items():
    row = []
    for column_name in columns:
        if column_name.lower() == 'name_part': # lower required due to above issue
            row.append(" ".join(item_data[column_name]))
        else:
            row.append(item_data[column_name])
    writer.writerow(row) 

csv_file.close()
```

My input is stored in file pd.json.The contents of pd.json are

```
{"status": "ok", "items": [{"work_phone_extension": null, "name_part": ["PATIENT", "TEST"], "residential_street_address_line_2": "", "referring_physician_first_name": "", "residential_street_address_line_1": "", "work_phone": "", "referring_physician_last_name": "", "residential_postal_or_zip_code": "", "referring_physician_code": "", "residence_phone": "416-", "health_card": "", "item_id": 1, "unique_vendor_id_sequence": 1, "cell_phone": null, "residential_city": "Toronto", "health_card_version": "", "residential_country_and_province_or_state": "CA_ON"}, {"work_phone_extension": null, "name_part": ["STEVE", "TEST"], "residential_street_address_line_2": "", "referring_physician_first_name": "Adam", "residential_street_address_line_1": "123 Fake St", "work_phone": "", "referring_physician_last_name": "Test", "residential_postal_or_zip_code": "M5E1Z8", "referring_physician_code": "123456", "residence_phone": "416-555-5555", "health_card": "", "item_id": 2, "unique_vendor_id_sequence": 2, "cell_phone": null, "residential_city": "Toronto", "health_card_version": "", "residential_country_and_province_or_state": "CA_ON"}]}
```

I'm executing the command

```
c:\python27\python.exe c:\Python27\Scripts\json2csv.py c:\Python27\Scripts\pd.json c:\Python27\Scripts\pd.txt
```

I keep getting the error

```
'Nonetype' object has no attribute keys.
```

Can somebody point out the error in json2csv at line first_item_id = item_data[0].keys()[0]

I'm tired of sitting and working on this code.

This code takes in pd.json and outputs the file as pd.txt

Comment: does that matter?i'm using python 2.7

Comment: In English, what are you trying to do? What do you *expect* `item_data[0].keys()[0]` to be, and *why*? What do you expect `item_data[0][first_item_id].keys()` to be, and why?

Answer (score 1):

Your error should be on `columns = item_data[0][first_item_id].keys()` line, and the problem is with `first_item_id`, I think you should change this:

```
first_item_id = item_data[0].keys()[0]
```

to this:

```
first_item_id = item_data[0]['item_id']
```

But it still has some problems, I think the code is not written for this json structure, I just changed another lines to fix it, I'm not sure this is the correct solution, but this is the thing that comes from your current code:

```
import sys, json, csv

input = open(sys.argv[1])
json_array = json.load(input)
input.close()

item_data = json_array["items"]
if len(item_data) >= 1:
    first_item_id = item_data[0]['item_id']
    columns = item_data[0].keys()

csv_file = open(sys.argv[2], "wb")
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
# there is currently a known bug where column names are partially uppercase, this will be fixed soon. the "map(lambda x: x.lower(), columns)" fixes this issue in the mean time
writer.writerow(map(lambda x: x.lower(), columns)) 

# here .items() is a standard python function
for item in item_data:
    row = []
    for column_name in columns:
        if column_name.lower() == 'name_part': # lower required due to above issue
            row.append(" ".join(item[column_name]))
        else:
            row.append(item[column_name])
    writer.writerow(row) 

csv_file.close()
```